# Is there standard range parameters on HTTP request made to fetch from an icalendar URL (ical, ics)?

Tags: web-services, outlook, icalendar

AFAIK, The icalendar RFC describes a file format.

Google calendar (for instance) can accessed through HTTP in various ways, one of them generates an ICS file.

However, imagine I have 30+ events per week during 5 years, --> 7 800 events, each ~ 10 lines long with ~ 80 bytes per line : an ICS generated for the whole calendar would be 7800x10x80 = 6 240 000 bytes, which by today storage/bandwidth standards is not that big, but kind of clumsy if I want to synchronize a Outlook/Thunderbird/other client with a remote calendar that can be only upgraded by ICS, and poll the remote ical server for changes too frequently...

In other words, is there a standard way of querying, with parameters, a web service that returns an ICS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's called CalDAV. Google calendar supports it, and many other calendar servers. Outlook however, does not (as a client)